# how to listview image passing another activity

Tags: android, image, listview, android-intent, android-activity

i'm beginner of android development.
this is my list images code. 
it won't passing images another activity. why it don't passing images another activity. can anyone fix it?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTop);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        textview.setText(data_topText[position]);
        imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View row) {
                    TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTop);
                    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);


                    String product = textview.getText().toString();
                    int images = imageview.getId();


                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SecondScreenActivity.class);

                    i.putExtra("name", product);
                    i.putExtra("zurag", images);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return (row);

    }
```

Here's SecondScreenActivity.java:

```
public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    int pic =intent.getIntExtra("zurag", 0);

    txtName.setText(name);
    images.setImageResource(pic);

}
```

}

Comment: What happens when you click the image?

Comment: there's nothing to images only screen2 layout

Comment: int images = getID(); will not return ImageResource, you have to implement some logic like storing an int array of ImageResources i.e drawable, then on onclicklistener pass that Resource in your intent

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setOnClickListener() for your row, try to use setOnItemClickListener() for your ListView:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View row, int position, long id) {
                TextView textview = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvTop);
                    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);


                    String product = textview.getText().toString();
                    int images = imageview.getId();


                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SecondScreenActivity.class);

                    i.putExtra("name", product);
                    i.putExtra("zurag", images);
                    startActivity(i);

            }

        });
```

Comment: @user1303250 Could you please debug, check what id do you get in `int images` and compare it to id of an image in clicked list item?

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTag() and getTag() when dynamically assigning Resource to your `Imageview`.

```
int images = getID(); // Will Not Return you Image Resource you set.
```

When assign ImageResource try setting Tag identity, this will help you in retrieving the imageresource in second activity.

```
imageView.setTag("any tag");
String imageTag =  (String) imageView.getTag(); // To retrieve
```

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 0):

It enough to just send position of the image on image array and retrieve in second activity...
In 1st Activity:

```
 i.putExtra("name", product);
 i.putExtra("pos", position);
```

In 2nd Activity:

```
int pic =intent.getIntExtra("pos", 0);
```

//and set 
   images.setImageResource(data_image[pic]);

Important: You need to keep image array(i.e data_image)even  in second activity .. Or you can try to send bitmap...

Comment: Glad dat it helped...pls accept answer if it solved your prblem